# not so simple group by date 2 data sets mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `jobs` table in my database.

job belongs to profession
job belongs to sector
job belongs to region

I would like to select jobs from the table and group them (count) by `date_published` field against another set of jobs with different `where` conditions applied.

For example I would like to select jobs that were published after 2012-01-01, group them by month/year to get monthly statistics and compare the sum against another set of jobs that have profession.id specified in where condition:

```
SELECT count(jobs.id),
       count(jobs2.id),
       DATE(jobs.date_published)
FROM jobs, jobs jobs2
WHERE jobs.date_published > '2010-01-01'
AND jobs.date_published = jobs2.date_published,
AND jobs2.profession_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(jobs.date_published),
    YEAR(jobs.date_published)
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(jobs.date_published) DESC,
    MONTH(jobs.date_published) DESC
```

But the above example is wrong because it causes the server to not respond and process the query for infinity. How can I fix it?

I believe it has something to do with the `jobs.date_published = jobs2.date_published` statement. There are many jobs in the system having the same `date_published` date.

Comment: Start by using explicit `JOIN` syntax. You should also not `SELECT`  attributes which are not in your aggregate.

Comment: Hi I used INNER JOIN to join the records but it didn't help with performance.

Answer (score 0):

Picking the date column in the select doesn't make any sense. You either need to group by the date, or select the year and month parts.

This kind of pattern should be quicker. Depending on exact requirements, you may be able to remove the nested query:

```
Select
  Year(date_published) Year,
  Month(date_published) Month,
  Sum(job_count_1) job_count_1,
  Sum(job_count_2) job_count_2
From (
    Select
      date_published,
      Sum(Case When profession_id In (1, 2, 3) Then 1 Else 0 End) as job_count_1,
      Count(*) as job_count_2
    From 
      jobs
    Where
      date_published > '2010-01-01'
    Group By 
      date_published
    Having
      Sum(Case When profession_id In (1, 2, 3) Then 1 Else 0 End) > 0
  ) a
Group By
  Year(date_published),
  Month(date_published)
Order By
  1 Desc,
  2 Desc
```

Having an index on (date_published, profession_id) will speed this up, as the engine should be able to answer the query just using the index.

Here's an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff663/1). With this data, what would you expect the answer to look like?

Comment: This looks very promising. I will let you know about results in a while.

Comment: How can I add additional filter statements? I would like to filter the data by sector_id and region_id also.

Comment: @user197483 It depends which side of the comparison you want to add them to. It would be much easier to answer with a small amount of example data and required results.

Comment: I would like to add different statements to different sides of the comparisons and also I would like to create more than 2 comparisons at the same time. The number of filters is simplified for this example but in the live database there are 9 filters to be dynamicly applied to depending on the user's choice.